# Get name of ruleset in DiagnosticAnalyzer implementation

Tags: roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Is there a way to get information on what ruleset (e.g. file name) is linked in the project properties from within of a `DiagnosticAnalyzer` implementation?

Comment: Just curious. Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You're not suppose to be passing data from your analyzer, to you're diagnostics in because they may not be deployed together in the future.

However with that being said IF you MUST there is a hack where you can send serialized data through one of the properties on the diagnosic span, but it is not recommeded

Comment: "from within [of] a `DiagnosticAnalyzer` implementation"... ?

Comment: oops didnt read that correctly I remember seeing something on that